# Replace specific local in a windows forms resource manager

Tags: c#, winforms, resx, resourcemanager

I have a windows forms application which is localized with a `Strings.resx` file and language specific `Strings.nl.resx` files.

These are compiled into the assembly which is fine. But now I want to give a contractor who is translating the app the ability to test his result directly in the app.

I already can read the resources from a `Strings.nl.resx` file on disk but how do I replace the values for the specific culture at runtime?

Comment: You can use reflection. It's not clear what is inside `Strings.resx` (seems like generated with resgen text file, right?).

Comment: **1-** Do you have access to source code? **2-** Can you build the application again?

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes, I have the source and I can rebuild. Currently I am giving the resx files to a contractor. He wants to try his translation without giving us the resx-file and recompile the app.

Comment: @SchlaWiener Using .resx files you need at least some sort of rebuild.